# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'

Tags: android, flutter, bundle, android-app-bundle, flutter-release

I can generate the bundle apk of debug as well as the build apk too. But when I tried to generate bundle release apk getting this error. Please help me to solve this

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'root/lib/getLibs.ps1' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: https://github.com/AS-Devs/signalr_flutter/issues/26 see this issue may help you

Comment: Thanks @shuabing . This really Solved my issue. I also used signalr in my project. I guess signalr has this comman issue.